# Python ODEINT problems with args

Tags: python, odeint

I am relatively new to Python and trying to use it to solve an integrator problem

```
x' = - L * x
```

Where L is the Laplacian Matrix, that is a matrix representation of a graph. This is part of my code:

```
def integrate_cons(x, t, l):
   xdot = -l*x
   return xdot;

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

#laplacian is a 3x3 matrix
#initial_condition is a vector
solution = odeint(integrate_cons, initial_conditions, t, args=(laplacian,))
print solution
```

I'm having problems to pass a matrix like an argument in odeint. How can i solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def integrate_cons(x, t, l):
   # unless you use np.matrix which I never do, you have to use np.dot
   xdot = -np.dot(l,x)
   return xdot;

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
# just a random matrix
l = np.random.rand(3,3)
# initial conditions
x0 = np.array([1,1,1])
#laplacian is a 3x3 matrix
#initial_condition is a vector
solution = odeint(integrate_cons, x0, t, args=(l,))
print(solution)
```

Look at the [scipy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/) for examples.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. Now i'm having problems to plot the solutions. I tried with `plt.plot(t, solution[:,0])`, but i get error "tuple indices must be integers, not tuple"